# How can i use a jinja2 template to output multiple commands in ansible?

Tags: ansible, output, jinja2

I have a task that calls on the commands variable. That runs multiple commands, but when I run the jinja2
template. I only get the show run back in my output file. Can someone help me get the other two commands
into the txt file, please?

```
- name: Sending a few simple Cisco IOS commands
 cisco.ios.ios_command:
   commands: "{{ commands }}"

commands:
- "show run"
- "show ip int brief"
- "show run | section ip route"

- name: Jinja2 Template
template:
  src: jinja2.j2
  dest: ./output/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt

{% for line in output.stdout_lines[0] -%}
{{ line }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome here. The example code you posted seems to be incorrect or incomplete. Not sure how you can iterate through `output.stdout_lines` without registering it first? Also the `commands` variable doesn't seem to be in the right place.

Comment: I left some of the elements out.

Comment: ---
- name: Sending IOS Commands
  hosts: paris
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Sending a few simple Cisco IOS commands
    cisco.ios.ios_command:
      commands:
        - sh run | in ntp|logging host|location|chassis|2c|priv|ACL_SNMP_EMS|ACL_SNMP_SERVICENOW|source
        - sh snmp user
    register: output
  - name: Jinja2 Template
    template:
      src: newline.j2
      dest: ./output/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt